# How to run php script on cron job in cpanel

Tags: php, cpanel

I schedule a new job on cronjob. But it's not working. Is there any way to run cronjob in cpanel using commands.

Comment: what you have tried?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow - nice to have you. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help keeping Stack Overflows content on the highest possible level and increase your chances getting an appropriate answer.

Comment: Its not corn, its cron

Answer (score 2):

There is a bunch of way to running script with CRON. I do use this way on my web application most of the time when I need to use CRON.

The first step is to choose a setting. The setting means when you want to run this script.

and after then simply just use `CURL` with `Cron` to get this work properly like this: `curl http://example.com/script.php` on command box and click on the add button and whola! You have successfully added your first `CRON` Task.

You may have a look at this picture below to get it properly
[image: Example uses Image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to CRON JOB option on your cpanle menus
Set url like this and set time according to your functionality

```
php /home/username/public_html/filename.php
```

Comment: Its not crone, its cron

Comment: Thank for your SPY EYE

Answer (score 0):

Run it in putty

- - - - - /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/project_name/artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1 this is for laravel project

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use like this - /usr/local/bin/ea-php74 /home/username/domainname.com/script_path/yourfile.php

replace **username** to your cpanel **username**, domain name to your **domain name**, **script path** where you want to run it, then replace the main file for corn job in **yourfile.php**